# Java instance variables

Tags: java

I am learning Java using Codecademy. I am trying to write code that would make an object (in this case a 3 year old dog named Spike) to run on on `n` legs where `n = age`. I tried "brute force debugging", but that didn't work. How should I change the line "how to change this" to make the code work?

```
class Dog {
    public Dog(int dogsAge) {
        int age = dogsAge;
    }

    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("Woof!");
    }

    public void run(int feet) {
        System.out.println("Your dog ran " + feet + " feet!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog spike = new Dog(3);
        spike.bark();
        spike.run(this.age); // How to change this?
    }
}
```

Comment: By declaring the variable `age` in the constructor, it's only visible within the constructor. This is an example of `scope`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class needs to 
  - add storage for the age variable
  - set that value in the construcor
  - provide a way for your main function to access it

```
class Dog {
 private int age; //storage for the age value within the instance
 public Dog(int dogsAge){
   this.age = dogsAge; // set the value
 }
 // provide a way to access the age
 public int getAge() {
   return this.age;
 }
 public void bark(){
   System.out.println("Woof!");

 }
 public void run(int feet) {
   System.out.println("Your dog ran " + feet + " feet!");
 }


 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Dog spike = new Dog(3);
  spike.bark();
  spike.run(spike.getAge()); // retrieve the age and use it
 }

}
```

Comment: What happens to a variable dogsAge if I don't add  "public int getAge() {   
   return this.age;   
 }"   ?   Is it completely unaccessible without dogsAge function?

Comment: In my code above it would not be inaccessible because the main() function is within the Dog class. However if the main() function were in another class, then it would be inaccessible without getAge() because the 'age' property was declared 'private'. You could make it accessible without the getAge() function, by using 'public int age' instead, however that is generally considered poor practise.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Dog {
int age;   //your mistake
 public Dog(int dogsAge){
 this.age = dogsAge;
 }
 public void bark() {
    System.out.println("Woof!");
}

public void run(int feet) {
    System.out.println("Your dog ran " + feet + " feet!");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dog spike = new Dog(3);
    spike.bark();
    spike.run(spike.age); // How to change this?
}
```

Comment: Dog.java:25: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context spike.run(this.age); // How to change this? ^ 1 error

Answer (score 2):

Try to create a variable `int age` and initialize it in constructor like this:

```
  class Dog {
  int age;
 public Dog(int dogsAge){
    this.age = dogsAge;
  }
```